# How to get session token of current user in wp_login hook?

Tags: hooks, login, cookies, session

I want to get current user's session token in the hook - wp_login.

I have tried this code in functions.php:

```
 add_action('wp_login','test');
  function test() {
  var_dump(wp_get_session_token()); //string(0) "" 
  exit;
    }
```

I am using wordpress 4.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access the `$_COOKIE` in this hook. You can only access `$_COOKIE` after the page HTTP headers are set with the `$_COOKIE` its mean in the next page.

You have other hook that you can hook into to get the cookies in the function `wp_set_auth_cookie()` there is this action at the end.

`do_action( 'set_logged_in_cookie', $logged_in_cookie, $expire, $expiration, $user_id, 'logged_in', $token );`

So you can use it like this:

```
add_action('set_logged_in_cookie', 'custom_get_logged_in_cookie', 10, 6);
function custom_get_logged_in_cookie($logged_in_cookie, $expire, $expiration, $user_id, $logged_in_text, $token) {
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: can I use this hook instead of wp_login?

Comment: basically I want to save session_token just after login. I do not want to use $_SESSION variable. wp_login does not provide session_token but set_logged_in_cookie provides. So I can use it. Please let me know if it is a wrong method to achieve this.

Comment: It is the best practice from what I see this hook is meant for this.